# Excluding a file in bash loop

Tags: bash

In the following script, How do I exclude a directory in the loop? I want to do this because all files are symlinks pointing to this directory that exists in the same level, so I don't want to add it.

```
cd /var/www
for dir in */
do
        base=$(basename "$dir")
        tar -czfh "${base}.tar.gz" "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add a `continue` statement like this :

```
cd /var/www
for dir in */
do
        if [ "$dir" == "foo" ] ; then
              continue;
        fi
        base=$(basename "$dir")
        tar -czfh "${base}.tar.gz" "$dir"
done
```

Or you can do it with `find` command :

```
find /var/www -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -name foo \) -prune -o -print -exec bash -c "tar -czfh \`basename {}\`.tar.gz {}" \;
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable `extglob` for this if it's not already enabled (`shopt -s extglob`):

```
for dir in !(dirname)/
...
```